# How to click on the next element using the first() and last() function in cypress?

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

In Cypress - The first() and last() functions in cypress picks or clicks on the first and last element inside the DOM. But what if I want to click the 2nd and the 3rd element.

Currently I am using below code to click on the first and last element :-

```
const fs = cy.get('div.outer-circle').first();
fs.click();

const ls = cy.get('div.outer-circle').last();
ls.click();
```

And I was trying to click on the second element. For which, I used next() functions also.

```
const ss = cy.get('div.outer-circle').next();
ss.click({multiple: true, force: true});
```

But unfortunately, it started clicking on all the elements.

Can anybody suggest here. How to go with this approach, I am pretty new to Cypress tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to choose specific index you have to use `.eq`([docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Syntax)). Example:

```
cy.get('div.outer-circle').eq(4);
```

The code above will return fourth element.

PS.
I would advise changing the way you store the elements. See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Asynchronous

Comment: Thank you, although this sort of relates to my issue; you helped me solve it! Thank you! cy.eq() Go figure!